# What is the execution order of if condition in JS

Tags: javascript, if-statement, arr

Given:

```
if(arr[0]!=null && arr[0].value.toString()!="") {
    //do something
}
```

Does an if conditional statement return false immediately after the first statement fails? Or does it check the second condition regardless?

Cheers,
Gavin :)

Comment: [Logical_Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: Boolean expressions are [short-circuited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: There's already useful answers. But just a comment to help in the future - it's very common when programming in javascript to use this short-circuiting for using an element only if it exists. Example `{elem && <p>{elem}</p>}`

Comment: maybe some more information is necessary, what is the usual content of `arr[0]`? could it be empty, `null`, or `undefined`? what is wtith the value? what type is it? `toString` and gaetting an empty string requires an empty string. why `toString`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends. If you are checking values with AND (`&&`) and the first value is `false`, the condition would immediately evaluate to `false` because every condition has to evaluate to `true`.

If you are checking values with OR (`||`) and the first condition is `false`, the if statement would check every other condition until it finds a `true` value.

Comment: And for this reason, another common tip to avoid "blowing up" is to use `||` to ensure a non-null value. Example: `var x = arr[0] || 1`

Comment: In more words - the evaluation starts on the left and works to the right.  Anything after a `&&` is only evaluated if the left hand side of it casts to `true`.  Just be aware of when brackets are used, which can group things together in less obvious ways.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If the first condition fails, then the rest of the checks won't work because of the [short circuit](http://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/short-circuit-evaluation-in-js/) functionality in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

`(arr[0]!=null && arr[0].value.toString()!="")` will directly return false when the `first` condition is false because you have used `&&` - while `(arr[0]!=null || arr[0].value.toString()!="")` would also evaluate the second condition after the first was false.

Answer (score 0):

```
`if(arr[0]!=null && arr[0].value.toString()!="") {
    //do something
}`
```

It is important to note this statement will be evaluated from left to right. Interpreter will evaluate fist condition and if fist value in array is null condition will be short circuit and jump out of the if block.

Answer (score -1):

It will return immediately, it won't throw an error if arr[0] is null.

Comment: "blow up"? what do you mean?

Comment: So all conditions always get check?

Comment: It will not check arr[0].value if arr[0] is null, it will return straight away, so it will skip the second check.

Comment: @GavinCreagh look up boolean short-circuiting